# What options are available to create a persistent unique key in tsql

Tags: t-sql, hash, key, persistence, unique

I've got data that has a primary key, but the key isn't persistent (not my data) so I've turned my attention to creating my own persistent key.  I've discovered Hashbytes, but i'm wondering if there is an option similar but of smaller size.
I have at least three data points that can be used for uniqueness.

Anyone know of something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use all 3 data points in a composite key

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable WITH CHECK ADD 
          CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (col1, col2, col3)
```

Keep it simple!

Personally, I would use all 3 columns (My personal best is a 13 column unique key, albeit a niche pattern of table use)

There is nothing really smaller then HASHBYTES that will give uniqueness except a simpler algorithm in HASHBYTES (MD5 = 16 bytes, SHA = 20 bytes etc)

Comment: I can't use this to reference the table though can I?  I need to be able to use it as a lookup key

Comment: Yes, you can lookup using multiple columns.